Map canvas stops working after layers are added via PyQGIS
I have created a script for automated map production using PyQGIS. One problem I encounter is that the map canvas freezes after I add layers using the following code under QGIS 3.34.6 LTR:
for layername in  temporary_layer_names:
    layer_path = geopackage_path + f"|layername={layername}"
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_path, layername, 'ogr')
    if not layer.isValid():
        raise Exception(f"Layer {layername} failed to load!")
    # adding layer to map
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

All layers are added correctly as you can see below:

But if I zoom in /change the map scale the canvas just behaves like a raster image, not updating the layer drawing. Also, additional layers I add manually using the QGIS GUI are not displayed:


Please add the QGIS version you use.
If you data are heavy or your rendering rules complex, It may take some times to load and render.
If you wait a little does the canvas comes back? Is there a progress bar showing at the bottom of the QGIS Interface when the canvas is "frozen"?

I added the QGIS version (3.34.6ltr). Data is not expecially heavy, just a few layers of OSM data and the problem occurs on every scale of city I tried. The Canvas does not seem to ever come back. If you mean the progress bar which shows the script execution, that one started, got to 100% and disappeared again. Only now it's frozen. I can still do things in the gui but those do not show on the map canvas. I can move the shown extent around, zoom in and out but the layers do not get rendered again. Tried with and without rendering acceleration

Thank's. From where do you run your script? python console? processing algorithm? custom plugin? Does the layer are added from a separate thread?

It's a custom script, run from the processing toolbox. I do not specifically use multithreading, so I suppose the layers are added from the same thread the whole script runs on. Also I now tried time.sleep(1) to slow down the adding process, but to no avail

Have you accidentally checked off the Render option in the lower right of the main QGIS window, next to the project CRS?

Nope. But I unchecked and rechecked it to see if it starts updating afterwards, which sadly it doesn't

The processing scripts are run in separate threads to avoid hanging QGIS main window.

please read: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags. If you are implementing this in the processAlgorithm() method of a QgsProcessingAlgorithm, it is no wonder the canvas is freezing. You will need to re-implement the flags() method and return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading.

Awesome! That did the trick. Never heard of it before. Thank you
